# Sqlite query - SELECT FROM returning 0 results

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Just started working with SQLite. I'm trying to find whether a name exists in my table of users. I'm doing it with this code:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.username = ?", (name,))
```

where name is a parameter (string) passed into function containing this code. From what I've seen in the documentation this is how I should be selecting using a parameter instead of a single value.

However using:

```
 print(len(cursor.fetchall()))
```

returns length 0. The users table exists and is populated with users including the one I'm trying to select. I've verified this in the query console.

Would appreciate any help as to what I'm doing wrong. I assume it's an issue with my query

Comment: Break it down to basics.  First try `cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users")` and see what results you get from that.

Comment: Also, why are you using `users.username` when the query already specifies the table?  I would have expected to see just `username`.  (I don't know that this is a problem, but it seemed unusual to me.)

Comment: That's my bad, it was originally username, just something I tried to get it to work with. And that's good advice thanks, I should have thought of that.

Comment: @JohnGordon Although not required in this simple query, prefixing the field name with the table name is neither unusual or going to cause a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your statement isn't the problem, for example:

```py
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute('DROP TABLE users')

cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE users (username TEXT, age INT)')
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO users VALUES ("john", 40)')
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO users VALUES ("mary", 52)')

cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.username = ?", ('john',))
print(cursor.fetchall())
```

You can run this and it will print:

```
[('john', 40)]
```

So, the problem is either with the value of `name` for which you didn't share the code, or with the database itself and it doesn't actually contain the record(s) you're trying to select, but you didn't share example data you're testing against. (or possibly, you think you're connecting to the database you want to connect to, but you're actually just connecting to another / a new one created when you run `.connect()`)

Comment: Thanks. You're right that it's not a problem with the query. Still investigating! But I think an issue with the way the databases are handled when I start my server